# Start with some C++ framework or python

Tags: c++, python, frameworks

I am thinking about to learn new language or framework. Now I deal with C# and WPF, WCF, Winforms. I have some free time so I would like get new skills.

But I have dilema, start with some C++ framework (such as Platinum, Reason, Evocosm, ACF)
or try Python / python framework.

I you are on my place which possibility you choose?

I am 17 years student, I have basic skills in C++ (OOP, little with STL), with Python I haven’t any experience.

What would be your choice and why?

Comment: This should be community wiki

Comment: I’ve been working with C++ for years. And I haven’t ever heard of any of those frameworks.

Comment: C++ has a premium collection of liberally-licensed libraries like boost, poco, Qt... Don't miss one of those in favor of a commercial one.

Comment: +1 for Konrad; using those "frameworks" is not really a very common scenario since it's usually more feasible to use the standard library (STL), Boost (an industry-standard extension to standard library) and **specialized** libraries for the very purposes one needs, like QT for GUI. A framework providing a given set of features would probably be just a limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I prefer Python, but profesionally, that is if you want a good job C++ is a better choice.

Answer (score 4):

Python is incredibly easy to learn, very powerful, and very useful (especially for web development IMO).

C++ is very widespread and is similar to other languages like C# and Java. Python's syntax is quite unique and AFAIK is not very similar to any other languages. Nonetheless, Python syntax is far easier to read and cleaner to write than C++.
Python is also fairly widespread and is used by huge companies like Google.

C++ has some wonderful libraries that can really help development, like Boost and Qt. Python also has excellent libraries like Django (for web development) and Twisted (for networking stuff). I find that C++ libraries tend to be broader in scope than Python libraries do, but the Python standard library is far better than the STL, IMO.

Python recently had a backwards-incompatible release (Python 3), and most libraries haven't caught up yet, so you might have to use Python 2 to take advantage of some of Python's libraries.

C++ is a lot faster than Python in terms of execution speed, but Python more than makes up for it in terms of development speed. Plus, Python allows you to write performance-critical parts of your application in C or C++.

Overall, I'd say go with Python, mostly because it's easy to learn and use, and [makes programming simple and fun](http://xkcd.com/353/).

Comment: Thank all for advice and their opinion, finally I choose C++.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to keep learning C++. Before you started looking for framework learn some popular search algorithm and try implement them. After that try implement some structures, like `queues`, `list`, `stack`, `binary trees` and some operation on them. Meanwhile play with `I/O` (for example, try write your stack to file and read it back to stack - in plain text and binary).

It was my university tour on programming class. C++ is good choice because it is hard and multiparadigmats language so in future u will find much in common with other languages and you will be familiar with memory management system.

Answer (score 0):

I'd pick C++ for the sole reason that it's nothing like the languages you already know, even though it shares some syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you at least learn a bit of Python first, even if you decide stay in C++.

One may say C++ is the most powerful program language.
However, for a starter, there are too many traps and pitfalls.

In your situation, Python is something that can let you know more about programming.
Since you have no experience in Python, It's very easy to learn at the beginning.
And it will show its effect very quickly.

Plus, learning it will help you understand C++ more, like STL and Boost, they all have similarities with Python. Qt even has PyQt as a Python bindings. They have the same API, while the syntax in Python is clean and elegant.

Here is a remarkable tutorial for Python: http://diveintopython3.org/

I suggest you just try it a bit, it wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Learning Python basics will take a week, and you will save the time spent in a year since it is such a good language for small hacks and scripts. So I suggest you learn it first.

Learning C++ well will take you five to ten years, so there is not the same immediate benefit :)